1) "A ten-thousand-dollar profit" — Can we say this without "dollar"? 2) "A ten-thousand-head growth" — Can we say this without "head"?
All examples below are mine.
(1a) a ten-thousand-dollar profit — I think this is correct.
(1b) a ten-thousand profit — Is this correct?
(2a) a ten-thousand-head growth — I think this is correct.
(2b) a ten-thousand growth — Is this correct?
(3a) a ten-thousand-strong army — I think this is correct.
(3b) a ten-thousand army — Is this correct?
The a-variants contain a measure: "dollar", "head" and "strong".
The b-variants don't contain a measure.
The a-variants have the pattern "number-measure + singular noun".
The b-variants have the pattern "number + singular noun".
As far as I understand, all a-variants are correct.
But I don't know about the b-variants.
Are (1b), (2b) and (3b) correct?
If not, then is there any rule explaining their incorrectness?

I have no formal basis for my comment, but to my ears your (b) examples sound unnatural. Perhaps it's because the number can be a noun or adjective, and the way you've written those sentences the extra word is included to avoid possible confusion. A ten-thousand army could be read as ten thousand armies, depending on where the story goes. But an army of ten thousand (soldiers) is clearly only one army, so the extra word soldiers can be omitted.

Counters such as "head" are not normally required if the context allows them to be infered.  You wouldn't say "There was a ten-thousand-head growth of the population" (it's not idiomatic) instead you'd say that "The population grew by ten-thousand".
Whereas "counters" like "head" or "strong" are not often used, units like "dollars" and "metres" are common. So "Profits increased by ten thousand dollars" is natural and the unit would normally be included, even if it might be inferred from context.  If you said "Profits increased by ten thousand" it might not be clear if you were talking about dollars, pounds, euros or yen!
So try to avoid words like "head" and "strong", but not words like "dollar".
